# Magento Blog Section

Tags: template, wordpress

There seems to be very little information out there about creating a Blog on Magento..

I am creating a clothing site for http://www.CrystelleClothing.co.uk and I want to include a blog section for trends and fasions etc...

There is an extension called BLOG (can be found at http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/free-stuff/blog.html and http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/blog-community-edition.html) which appears to do this and whilst reviews are good, there is no screen shots etc.

Has anybody used this BLOG extension, or am I best off creating a wordpress blog in the site? or something similar?

Would be useful for a lot of people I think

Comment: Just take the plugin, throw it on your staging or dev instance, if you don't like it, reset the instance, I'm, sure you are using some kind of VCS. and make a backup of the database!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently installed it. It seems to work well although I haven't tested it live.

Developing right now.

Note it has a widget you can use in a custom CMS block for recent posts.

Comment: Hi there, are you talking about BLOG or FISHPIG? Thanks

Comment: @HenryAspden I am talking about the Aheadworks blog module.

Comment: Thanks :D Thanks all I needed to know... Perfect answer...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest giving the Fishpig Wordpress module a whirl - http://fishpig.co.uk/wordpress-integration.html It connects a separate WordPress installation to Magento and you can embed posts in your Magento theme. It's free so no harm if you don't like it.